# How to make a variable to show the same row as it is currently showing in PHP?

Tags: php, database

I really don't know how to explain this question. But, I'm trying to make a product page that shows the same row as it is currently showing (so example "go onto a tech product page and at the bottom it shows all other tech related products").

Here is what I've tried:

```
<?php 
    $pType = $row['typeP'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE type=$pType";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
    echo "<a href='products.php?id={$row['productID']}'>";
    echo "<img src='uploads/{$row['displayIMG']}'>";
    echo "</a>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to sql injection, and i am not getting your question could you make it  little bit clear

Comment: Where is the error ?

Answer (score 0):

Your error would be in the $typeP declaration. I am guessing $row is not defined before that. therefor it is empty. Maybe you were trying to use a GET?

```
<?php 
    $pType = $_GET['typeP']; //This would get the type id from the querystring
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE type='".$pType."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
         echo "<a href='products.php?id=".$row['productID']."'>";
         echo "<img src='uploads/".$row['displayIMG']."'>";
         echo "</a>";
    }
?>
```

I should also mention that your code is subject to SQL injection. Please clean your inputs before running them through you database. Otherwise you are asking for trouble.
http://www.wikihow.com/Prevent-SQL-Injection-in-PHP